# C# MYSQL Database connection working on laptop but not on desktop

Tags: c#, mysql

Im new to C# and MYSQL so dont judge me. So basicly im useing this code to connect to my MYSQL database and creating an account in the database, this code is working just fine on my laptop but dossent seem to be working on my desktop i have no idea why, any sugestions ?

```
private void createaccountBT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection;
        string server = "********";
        string database = "********";
        string uid = "********";
        string password = "********";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into  users (Username,Password) values(@Username,@Password)", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", createusernametxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pwboxcr8user.Password);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Account sucesfully created");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" an error occured. Please try again later.");
            }
    }
```

EDIT: It is an online server and its all written correctly its directly copy pasted from the laptop where it works like a charm, also i marked an something as an answer and i dont think how to undo it since this is my first post, sorry about that.

Comment: If it works on place A and not on place B, then the code is most likely not your issue: Try to login into mysql using the mysql command line tool on both systems and see what response you get.

Comment: The server isn't set to localhost, right?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code.  When you try it on your desktop, make sure that the connection variables (server, database, uid, password) are adjusted to connect to the database on your desktop, not still aimed at your laptop.  If you're connecting to the same database in both cases, it it on your laptop or desktop, or still a third system?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your database is set up locally, not online. If you are hosting your MySQL database locally, you likely have the server connection string set to "localhost" or the IP of your laptop. Of course, the database then doesn't exist on your desktop.

Fix: Host your MySQL database online, using the connection strings of whatever host you decide to use. (Example: GoDaddy with phpMyAdmin [built-in MySQL DB])